# SDL2_image::SDL2_image target was not found when installed with vcpkg

Tags: cmake, sdl-2, vcpkg

I have a C++ project with CMake as build system.
I am using the dependencies SDL2 and SDL2_image in this project. It was building fine, when adding this dependencies via `FetchContent`. But I wanted to transition to using `find_package` so I don't have to build all the dependencies on every rebuild.
So I moved everything to `find_package` and installed `sdl2` and `sdl2-image` with vcpkg.

vcpkg.json

```json
    {
      "dependencies": [
        "sdl2",
        "sdl2-image"
      ],
      "builtin-baseline": "1b65197e9393b9ca312c95731ebf9c53d776b8d2"
    }
```

CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(Sdl2App)

find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(Sdl2App 
    "./main.cpp"
)

target_link_libraries(Sdl2App PRIVATE
    SDL2::SDL2
    SDL2_image::SDL2_image
)
```

Now my problem is, as soon as I build this project, CMake complains it can't find the target `SDL2_image::SDL2_image`

Build

```
➜  sdl2-build-error cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/ascendise/Dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
-- Running vcpkg install
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-linux...
All requested packages are currently installed.
Total install time: 390 ns
sdl2 provides CMake targets:

    find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main
        PRIVATE
        $<TARGET_NAME_IF_EXISTS:SDL2::SDL2main>
        $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:SDL2::SDL2>,SDL2::SDL2,SDL2::SDL2-static>
    )

sdl2-image provides CMake targets:

    find_package(SDL2_image CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:SDL2_image::SDL2_image>,SDL2_image::SDL2_image,SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static>)

-- Running vcpkg install - done
-- Configuring done (0.8s)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "Sdl2App" links to:

    SDL2_image::SDL2_image

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.



-- Generating done (0.0s)
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

I can't figure out, why CMake won't find the target `SDL2_image::SDL2_image`. It is listed in the vcpkg install output as one of the available targets.

When I install the dependencies through pacman, CMake has no problem finding both packages and their targets (given that vcpkg is not passed in CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE). But I still need to use vcpkg on other machines...

One curiosity I found, was that when I try to link to SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static, the build succeeds. But I want to link to the shared library. (As far as I understood there, if I would link to SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static, it would not use the users SDL installation but the SDL2_image code would just be compiled into my app?).

Also it just seems weird, because given the usage text for sdl2-image (see Build), it is mentioned that if the target `SDL2_image::SDL2_image` exists, both `SDL2_image::SDL2_image` and `SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static` should be available?

So where exactly does my problem lie? Did I misconfigure anything? If it is a bug, then how come no one else seems to have this problem?

Comment: "Also it just seems weird, because given the usage text for sdl2-image (see Build), it is mentioned that if the target SDL2_image::SDL2_image exists, both SDL2_image::SDL2_image and SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static should be available?" - No the given generator expression means that one should link with `SDL2_image::SDL2_image` **if that target exists**, otherwise one should link with `SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static` target. It looks like in your case vcpkg builds only the static library, thus only `SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static` target is available for link with.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok, that makes a much more sense. I checked my vcpk_installed folder and saw that I only have the files: `libSDL2.a` `libSDL2_image.a` and `libSDL2main.a`. So only static libraries... But SDL2 has the same expression, so why does CMake still find the `SDL2::SDL2` target? If I try to build my example project with only SDL2 it can also build fine...

Comment: "so why does CMake still find the SDL2::SDL2 target?" - Probably, you have shared SDL2 library installed via vcpkg. Also note, that It is up to the project which libraries to build and how to name their targets. So, do not expect that every project Foo will create targets `Foo::Foo` and `Foo::Foo-static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Original answer from Petruska on discource.libsdl.ord](https://web.archive.org/web/20240127195141/https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl2-image-sdl2-image-target-was-not-found-when-installed-with-vcpkg/48751)

Vcpkg defaults to building static libraries on Linux and shared libraries on Windows. That's why the usage text from SDL2 recommends the 'complex' target_link_libraries with the if else. (also explains, why I couldn't reproduce it on Windows...)
So this way, you can build on multiple platforms and it just defaults to whatever is available.

So by changing the CMakeLists.txt to the following, I was able to build the project:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21) project(Sdl2App)

find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED) find_package(SDL2_image CONFIG REQUIRED) add_executable(Sdl2App 
    "./main.cpp" )

target_link_libraries(Sdl2App PRIVATE
    $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:SDL2::SDL2>,SDL2::SDL2,SDL2::SDL2-static>
    $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:SDL2_image::SDL2_image>,SDL2_image::SDL2_image,SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static> )
```